# Geb hitting dropdown form elements: (error-couldn't select option with text or value)

Tags: jquery, functional-testing, geb

I'm writing some Geb test for a form.  For some reason I can't hit any of the dropdowns in my form.

Example field:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    State<g:select name="submitterState" from="stuff..." class="form-control" optionKey="id" required="" value=""/>
</div>
```

I've written the test itself three different ways and none of them hit the select. Where 102727 is one of the values of the dropdown.

```
$('#submitterState').value(102727)
$("form").submitterState = 102727
$('select', name: 'submitterState').value(102727)
```

Do I have something wrong with my test, or is there something behind it I'm not seeing?
-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, can you select a property with '#'? '#' is used to select an id.

I think you should pass a string instead of an integer.

```
$('#submitterState').value('102727')
```

But this will not work. You should try something like this:

```
$('div.col-sm-2').find('select', name: 'submitterState').value('102727')
```

Hope, your problem will be solved!

Comment: sorry I haven't got back to you sooner.  I never got around to working on that piece again.  What you suggested did not work for me.   Are there any other ideas?